# Regular Expressions - Parsing logs

Tags: regex, parsing

I have this log -

```
MySite Access reject(60) - Redirect to user page
```

I want to be able to parse it so that `(60)` will be in one group and the rest in another.

What I currently use is

```
([A-Za-z  \-\(\)\d]+)
```

which takes in all of it. The problem being that when trying to group the first part of it which is ***`MySite Access reject`*** it recognizes the word reject with (60) as one word. I don't know how to get them to be set apart.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output, and what language/tool are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 
The expected output is to have two groups
1. MySite Access reject - Redirect to user page
2. 60
I am using a SIEM of mcafee and I am trying to create parser rules

Comment: Where is the `2` coming from, and how did `60` end up at the end?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i don't think you understood what I was trying to say, the **2** was just to mark it in the different group.     

I want to be able to extract those two pieces of information, the number inside the () and the rest of the log.

Comment: If you can live with having 60 in the text group too, (.*\((\d+)\).*) should work https://regex101.com/r/RNXgxc/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use three capture groups to isolate the two text components and number in parentheses.

**Find:**

```
^[^(]+\((\d+)\)(.*)$
```

**Replace:**

```
$1 $3 $2
```

### Demo

Note that for the sake of readability you might want to add some sort of separator between the log text and number.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are using bash only and you have the line above in a file called `log.log` I would use the following to select the text only and the number (with the parentheses) only respectively.

`cat log.log | sed 's/([0-9].)//g'
cat log.log | grep -o '([0-9]\+)'`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind processing one line twice? What I mean is,

you can first do a match to get the number. Here, 60.
i.e. `\(([\d]+)\)`

You can again do a match to get just the text.
i.e. `[^\(\d\)]`